# Fluent NHibernate - Error dehydrating property value; given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a class called `ProjectTaskBudget` that has a property of type `IBudgetableIncomeStream`, like so:

```
public class ProjectTaskBudget
{
    public virtual IBudgetableIncomeStream BudgetableIncomeStream { get; set; }
}
```

`IBudgetableIncomeStream` is an interface that's applied to, among other things, an abstract class called `Deliverable`:

```
public abstract class Deliverable : IBudgetableIncomeStream
{
    // Some stuff
}
```

and a concrete class called `RecurringIncomeLine`:

```
public class RecurringIncomeLine : IBudgetableIncomeStream
{
    // Some stuff
}
```

The concrete classes that inherit from `Deliverable` are `DeliverableItem` and `DeliverableTime`.

The mapping for `ProjectTaskBudget` looks like this:

```
public class ProjectTaskBudgetMap : MappingBase<ProjectTaskBudget>
{
    public ProjectTaskBudgetMap()
    {
        ReferencesAny(n => n.BudgetableIncomeStream)
            .EntityTypeColumn("IncomeStreamType")
            .EntityIdentifierColumn("IncomeStream_id")
            .AddMetaValue<Deliverable>("Deliverable")
            .AddMetaValue<RecurringIncomeLine>("RecurringIncomeLine")
            .IdentityType<Guid>();
    }
}
```

This works as it should with the `RecurringIncomeLine`, so I suspect the problem is to do with the abstract/interface mapping.
When I try to add a new `ProjectTaskBudget` to the database using a `Deliverable`, and flush, I get this error:

```
NHibernate.PropertyValueException: Error dehydrating property value for xxx.xxx.xxx.ProjectTaskBudget.BudgetableIncomeStream ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at NHibernate.Type.MetaType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Type.AnyType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, Boolean[] settable, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement, ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement, ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   at hiJump.Infrastructure.DataAccess.EventListeners.FixedDefaultFlushEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session) in c:\code\Git\Harmony\SharedCode\hiJump\hiJump.Infrastructure\DataAccess\EventListeners\FixedDefaultFlushEventListener.cs:line 35
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
```

I'm wondering if applying the interface directly to `DeliverableItem` and `DeliverableTime` would make a difference, and have the mapping include

```
.AddMetaValue<DeliverableItem>("DeliverableItem")
.AddMetaValue<DeliverableTime>("DeliverableTime")
```

but that's a reasonably big refactor, so I wanted to check first and see if I was missing anything more obvious, or if that sounded like nonsense.

Comment: Does it work if you just remove `.AddMetaValue<Deliverable>("Deliverable")` and add `.AddMetaValue<DeliverableItem>("DeliverableItem")` and `.AddMetaValue<DeliverableTime>("DeliverableTime")` without actually changing the classes? Changing the classes should be unnecessary, because they already implement `IBudgetableIncomeStream` via their base class.

Comment: I did try that, forgot to mention, it returns the same error.

Comment: Please make sure that NHibernate is not trying to save `Deliverable` to its own table.

Comment: Figured it out, the actual thing being persisted in my case as a subclass of DeliverableItem, mapping didn't like it. Can't answer my own question for another six hours, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. The problem was in the mapping, but not what I thought.

The `IBudgetableIncomeStream` it was trying to add was in fact
something that derived from `DeliverableItem`, so mapping
`DeliverableItem` wasn't enough, I have to put in every subclass of
`DeliverableItem` and `DeliverableTime` in the mapping, like:

```
.AddMetaValue<DeliverableItemSubclass1>("DeliverableItemSubclass1")
.AddMetaValue<DeliverableItemSubclass2>("DeliverableItemSubclass2")
.AddMetaValue<DeliverableTimeSubclass1>("DeliverableTimeSubclass1")
```